is there a way to authenticate users running Gitlab CI Jobs against LDAP / AD?
i am researching how to secure Gitlab CI deployment pipelines by authenticating users against LDAP. I could not find a formal way to implement this. Is there any?
The only way i can think of is to manually search in LDAP using a script and determine if a user exists in pre-created groups with names matching CI environments.
something like:
#!/bin/python
memberOf = get_ldap_groups(user)
if group not in memberOf:
  print(f"User is not allowed to deploy on {group}")
  sys.exit(1)


Trying to write it to a file is not a good idea since the user himself will be able to modify the file.
The correct solution is to manage at the gitlab permissions level (owner, maintainers, developers) in order to know if the user can 'Allowed to merge' 'Allowed to push and merge' on the protected branches. (Settings -> Repository -> Protected branches)
Then you must then create an environment variable only accessible on protected branches. (Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables -> Add variable -> Check Protect variable)
This environment variable will contain a token read by the runner which will authorize or not the execution of the pipeline.

This is not really my question though. Your suggestion is the traditional way of doing things in Gitlab-CI which is very limited and doesn't integrate with LDAP. It might work for people who dont care about LDAP integration. Also Scripts can be protected by using external Repository where this script exists. Then simply using include keyword in main repository.
